# Horizontal scrolling menu width in jQuery

Tags: jquery, html, css

I'm trying to make a horizontal scrolling menu bar like this:

```css
div.scrollmenu {
  background-color: #333;
  overflow: auto;
  white-space: nowrap;
}

div.scrollmenu a {
  display: inline-block;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 14px;
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="scrollmenu">
  <a href="#home">Home</a>
  <a href="#news">News</a>
  <a href="#contact">Contact</a>
  <a href="#about">About</a>
  <a href="#support">Support</a>
  <a href="#blog">Blog</a>
  <a href="#tools">Tools</a>
  <a href="#base">Base</a>
  <a href="#custom">Custom</a>
  <a href="#more">More</a>
  <a href="#logo">Logo</a>
  <a href="#friends">Friends</a>
  <a href="#partners">Partners</a>
  <a href="#people">People</a>
  <a href="#work">Work</a>
</div>
```

My question is: how can I get the full width of `.scrollmenu` in jQuery? I mean its shown + hidden parts. If I use `$(".scrollmenu").width();` I just get the width of the visible part of that div.

Comment: @RyanL just click on the link he provided in the question and you can see it on the w3school website.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To access the DOM Element's  list of properties you can use **jQuery**'s `.prop()` like `$("selector").prop("scrollWidth")`

or directly using pure **JavaScript**: [`Element.scrollWidth`<sup>*MDN Docs*</sup>](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/scrollWidth)

```js
// jQuery:
console.log( $(".scrollmenu").prop("scrollWidth") );
// JS
console.log( document.querySelector(".scrollmenu").scrollWidth );
```

```css
div.scrollmenu {
  background-color: #333;
  overflow: auto;
  white-space: nowrap;
}

div.scrollmenu a {
  display: inline-block;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 14px;
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="scrollmenu">
  <a href="#home">Home</a>
  <a href="#news">News</a>
  <a href="#contact">Contact</a>
  <a href="#about">About</a>
  <a href="#support">Support</a>
  <a href="#blog">Blog</a>
  <a href="#tools">Tools</a>
  <a href="#base">Base</a>
  <a href="#custom">Custom</a>
  <a href="#more">More</a>
  <a href="#logo">Logo</a>
  <a href="#friends">Friends</a>
  <a href="#partners">Partners</a>
  <a href="#people">People</a>
  <a href="#work">Work</a>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks Roko, clear and simple explanation.

Comment: Very interesting this use of `.prop()`. I did not find a reference on jquery official website about the possibility to select also this kind of things. Is there any documentation about it? I'd be curious

Comment: @LucaDetomi https://api.jquery.com/prop/ is used to get or set properties of a DOM 
 Node. The description in the jQuery docs seems quite OK I think.

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan yes, I already read this link but in it, for example, it is not cited any 'width' properties or something similar, so I did not figured out that could be possible also to get this kind of informartions, I thought only equivalent of explicit "attributes"

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `scrollWidth` property. It is a JavaScript property and there is no equivalent in jQuery.

```js
function getWidth() {
  console.log($(".scrollmenu")[0].scrollWidth);
}
```

```css
div.scrollmenu {
  background-color: #333;
  coverflow: auto;
  white-space: nowrap;
}

div.scrollmenu a {
  display: inline-block;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 14px;
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="scrollmenu">
  <a href="#home">Home</a>
  <a href="#news">News</a>
  <a href="#contact">Contact</a>
  <a href="#about">About</a>
  <a href="#support">Support</a>
  <a href="#blog">Blog</a>
  <a href="#tools">Tools</a>
  <a href="#base">Base</a>
  <a href="#custom">Custom</a>
  <a href="#more">More</a>
  <a href="#logo">Logo</a>
  <a href="#friends">Friends</a>
  <a href="#partners">Partners</a>
  <a href="#people">People</a>
  <a href="#work">Work</a>
</div>
<br/>
<button type="button" onclick="getWidth()">Get width</button>
```

Answer (score -1):

I'd recommend wrapping your horizontal scroll menu in a div, then find the width of the parent. https://jsfiddle.net/qegufbv8/1/

```
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="scrollmenu">
    <a href="#home">Home</a>
    <a href="#news">News</a>
    <a href="#contact">Contact</a>
    <a href="#about">About</a>
    <a href="#support">Support</a>
    <a href="#blog">Blog</a>
    <a href="#tools">Tools</a>  
    <a href="#base">Base</a>
    <a href="#custom">Custom</a>
    <a href="#more">More</a>
    <a href="#logo">Logo</a>
    <a href="#friends">Friends</a>
    <a href="#partners">Partners</a>
    <a href="#people">People</a>
    <a href="#work">Work</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

You can then use jQuery `.width()` to find the width.

```
$( '.wrapper' ).width();
```

If your scrollmenu div width is less than 100%, make sure to add `display: inline-block` to your wrapper.